# Taxonomy question how to add more data

Tags: customization, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

Normally taxonomy has a name and a value in the template I'm using it has a name value and what they call category what I'm wondering is what function call in PHP do you use to set that category I know how to set up a taxonomy with a name and a value but that doesn't seem to be the right function.

Here is an image for some help and I do not know how to explain this as I do not know the proper terms to use... https://ibb.co/KrBMdD1 so.... how do I add to the Category heading using PHP... hope that helps!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. "in the template I'm using it has a name value and what they call category" Can you show what you mean by this?

Comment: Thats probably my problem I googled for hours for the answer but I do not know the proper terms to google! Here is some images. https://ibb.co/KrBMdD1 so.... how do I add to the Category heading using PHP... hope that helps!

Comment: Are you trying to add a taxonomy to a taxonomy?  You would want to use Parent->Child instead.  So `BMW` as the parent.  Then the children would be `5 Series`, `4 Series`, `3 Series` etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is not a standard WordPress feature. Taxonomies do not typically have their own category, and there's no standard method for doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and sorry for the confusion, it's `update_term_meta()` function, never knew taxonomy could have meta data :-)

Thanks for every ones attempt to help...

R.